# Unit testing in Vuex throwing AssertionError to equal { Object (type, text) }

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocha.js, chai, vuex

So far unit testing Vuex actions have been a nightmare, I can't seem to understand what it's actually looking for. I'm following https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/testing.html and using their action helper function.

I have a simple action that will add text to a button.

```
createButton({ commit, state }, payload) {
    let btnString = '';

    if (payload.hasCookie) {
        btnString = 'Welcome back';
    } else if (payload.isLoggedIn) {
        btnString = 'Sign out';
    } else {
        btnString = 'Sign up';
    }

    commit({ type: 'CREATE_BUTTON_TEXT', text: btnText });
},
```

In my test...

```
describe('Create Button Text', () => {
        it('should render the buttons string ', (done) => {
            const expectedString = 'Welcome back';
            const mock = {
                hasCookie: true,
                isLoggedIn: false,
            };

            testAction(actions.createButton, mock, state, [
                { type: 'CREATE_BUTTON_TEXT', text: expectedString },
            ], done);
        });
    });
```

It's returning `AssertionError: expected 'CREATE_BUTTON_TEXT' to equal { Object (type, text) }`... Am I not providing the expected `text` with `expectedString` correctly? Any guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

(Using Mocha + Chai as per recommendation in the docs).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your commit syntax is wrong. If you used the `testAction` helper, the argument `expectedMutations` expects a list of objects with type and payload.
The following code works for me:

```
createButton({ commit, state }, payload) {
  let btnString = ''

  if (payload.hasCookie) {
    btnString = 'Welcome back'
  } else if (payload.isLoggedIn) {
    btnString = 'Sign out'
  } else {
    btnString = 'Sign up'
  }

  commit('CREATE_BUTTON_TEXT', btnString)
}
```

And test method:

```
describe('Create Button Text', () => {
 it('should render the buttons string ', (done) => {
  const expectedString = 'Welcome back'
  const mock = {
   hasCookie: true,
   isLoggedIn: false
  }

  testAction(actions.createButton, mock, {}, [
   { type: 'CREATE_BUTTON_TEXT', payload: expectedString }
  ], done)
 })
})
```